# svn: Source and dest appear not to be in the same repository

Tags: svn

I have source code checked in to SVN which I am trying to move or copy from one location to another

Here the SVN command is what I tried:

```
svn copy https://source1/svn/projects/folder1 https://source1/svn/projects/folder2
```

This is not working, and it returns an error

> "svn: Source and dest appear not to be in the same repository"

Help please?

Comment: Compare UUIDs in `svn info URL1` and `svn info URL2`. They are different and there are two different repos in action, sure

Comment: In that case how can I copy from one svn repo to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do check-out your code into a working copy and then import this code to your new repository.

```
svn checkout <url1> [working copy path]
svn import [working copy path] <url2> -m "import from <url1>"
```

I just recognized, you want to copy/move within your repository.
Then your command is right but do not forget to set a message:

```
svn move <url><path1> <url><path2> -m "moved from <path1>"
```

Comment: you're right I think it was the missing message (-m)